# What is the purpose of cylinder "second power bricks" on cords?

Tags: power-supply, wire

I have noticed a large number of power cords that have a PSU built into them also have a second brick on them. What is the purpose of this "second power brick"?

Example, Xbox 360 Power Adapter:

[image: Xbox 360 Power Adapter]

---

I dug through my old electronics and found other devices that have the cylinder  add on, as well as an USB type A to Micro USB adapter that also had the cylinder. This suggests that the cylinder might not be exclusive to AC to DC power adapters.

USB type A to Micro USB adapter:
[image: USB type A to Micro USB adapter]

Comment: It's not called a brick. Its a ferrite cylindrical clamshell

Comment: it is not `power cords that have a PSU built into them`  .... it is an external power adapter or an external power supply .... the power cord supplies AC power to the power adapter ... some versions of power adapters plug into the power outlet directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a ferrite choke. It's ring of ferrite that the cable runs through. Think of it as a one-turn inductor where the core materials is lossy at high frequency so high frequencies energy get dissipated as heat. You can buy them separately as rings of ferrite and actually wind more than one turn of the cable through them, if you wish. Or as clamshells that clamp around the cable.

It is there to stop the cable from becoming an antenna that radiates or picks up noise, and suppresses external noise from entering the system through the cable, and keeps noise in the system from exiting the system through the cable.

Answer (score 2):

So it is called a plastic-molded split clamshell ferrite EMI Common-Mode (CM) Choke made of high permeability Ferrite to raised CM impedance and balance the currents in each direction so they radiate less  EM noise and pass IEC / FCC requirements.

All VGA cables have these too.

So it is a "ferrite CM choke on cord" *not a brick on a cord.*

They are also available for the aftermarket with snaps.  The flat interface surface gap must be so tight that a "bug's whisker" could reduce its performance. [image]

The cable as an antenna isn't perfectly balanced and still causes EMI issues to some users.

---

[*Ref*](https://www.mpja.com/040in-ID-Ferrite-Clamshell-EMI-Filter/productinfo/17842%20FL/)

CM Chokes come in a variety of frequency bands and also also known as BALUNs.

"Bricks" is the euphanism for brick-shaped ACDC converters.

Comment: I assume you mean the gap between the halves of the ferrite core when you're talking about performance reduction.  Are there any precautions I should know about when closing one, or is it sufficient to make sure the faces of the ferrite are clean and the enclosure will squeeze tightly enough to prevent an air gap?  As far as I understand these are mostly to prevent high frequency interference and surges, so they don't do much below ~1MHz?

Comment: The ones in my link are from 25MHz to above 500MHz.
Impeadance: 125 ohm @ 25MHz
275 ohm @ 100MHz. Gaps are <um with glass flat finish which tend to be brittle, chip easily.

Comment: Wow.  I never would have guessed there was such a high spec on those.  Really appreciate all your work on here.

Comment: When they want to use ferrite as an energy conversion part, the energy is stored in the gap and the permeability drops so it can handle more differential current starting with gaps of 100um but then as a CM choke that drops the impedance and loses the 150 or more impedance needed for BALUN function ( to balance lines <1 Ohm for ground and raise it > 100 Ohms)